# How to change SVG color when it is an encoded CSS background image?

Tags: html, css, svg, background-image

I have a SVG icon that is encoded in my CSS file. How do I change the color of it on hover without having a duplicate icon in a different color?

In my CSS file I have:

```
background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 511.999 511.999'%3E%3Cpath fill='red' d='M83.578 167.256H16.716C7.524 167.256 0 174.742 0 183.971v300.881c0 9.225 7.491 16.713 16.716 16.713h66.862c9.225 0 16.716-7.489 16.716-16.713V183.971c0-9.229-7.525-16.715-16.716-16.715zM470.266 167.256c-2.692-.456-128.739 0-128.739 0l17.606-48.032c12.148-33.174 4.283-83.827-29.424-101.835-10.975-5.864-26.309-8.809-38.672-5.697-7.09 1.784-13.321 6.478-17.035 12.767-4.271 7.233-3.83 15.676-5.351 23.696-3.857 20.342-13.469 39.683-28.354 54.2-25.952 25.311-106.571 98.331-106.571 98.331v267.45h278.593c37.592.022 62.228-41.958 43.687-74.749 22.101-14.155 29.66-43.97 16.716-66.862 22.102-14.155 29.66-43.97 16.716-66.862 38.134-24.423 25.385-84.871-19.172-92.407z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
```

As you can see it's red from the **fill='red'** attribute.

When a user hovers over the icon with this background SVG, how can I change the color of it to blue?  The only solution I see is to create another CSS class with the same SVG code except with a different fill color, but that just adds more to the file size and seems redundant.

Comment: Can you move the `svg` to the markup instead of it being a `background-image` ? If so,  you can take a look at https://codepen.io/luiscarvalho/pen/hJFrx

Answer (score 10):

You can use the filter property:

```css
.box {
  background: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 511.999 511.999'%3E%3Cpath fill='red' d='M83.578 167.256H16.716C7.524 167.256 0 174.742 0 183.971v300.881c0 9.225 7.491 16.713 16.716 16.713h66.862c9.225 0 16.716-7.489 16.716-16.713V183.971c0-9.229-7.525-16.715-16.716-16.715zM470.266 167.256c-2.692-.456-128.739 0-128.739 0l17.606-48.032c12.148-33.174 4.283-83.827-29.424-101.835-10.975-5.864-26.309-8.809-38.672-5.697-7.09 1.784-13.321 6.478-17.035 12.767-4.271 7.233-3.83 15.676-5.351 23.696-3.857 20.342-13.469 39.683-28.354 54.2-25.952 25.311-106.571 98.331-106.571 98.331v267.45h278.593c37.592.022 62.228-41.958 43.687-74.749 22.101-14.155 29.66-43.97 16.716-66.862 22.102-14.155 29.66-43.97 16.716-66.862 38.134-24.423 25.385-84.871-19.172-92.407z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E") center/cover;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.box:hover {
  filter: hue-rotate(210deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

Another idea is to use the icon as mask and you can easily adjust the color by setting the background-color:

```css
.box {
  -webkit-mask: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 511.999 511.999'%3E%3Cpath fill='red' d='M83.578 167.256H16.716C7.524 167.256 0 174.742 0 183.971v300.881c0 9.225 7.491 16.713 16.716 16.713h66.862c9.225 0 16.716-7.489 16.716-16.713V183.971c0-9.229-7.525-16.715-16.716-16.715zM470.266 167.256c-2.692-.456-128.739 0-128.739 0l17.606-48.032c12.148-33.174 4.283-83.827-29.424-101.835-10.975-5.864-26.309-8.809-38.672-5.697-7.09 1.784-13.321 6.478-17.035 12.767-4.271 7.233-3.83 15.676-5.351 23.696-3.857 20.342-13.469 39.683-28.354 54.2-25.952 25.311-106.571 98.331-106.571 98.331v267.45h278.593c37.592.022 62.228-41.958 43.687-74.749 22.101-14.155 29.66-43.97 16.716-66.862 22.102-14.155 29.66-43.97 16.716-66.862 38.134-24.423 25.385-84.871-19.172-92.407z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E") center/cover no-repeat;
          mask: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 511.999 511.999'%3E%3Cpath fill='red' d='M83.578 167.256H16.716C7.524 167.256 0 174.742 0 183.971v300.881c0 9.225 7.491 16.713 16.716 16.713h66.862c9.225 0 16.716-7.489 16.716-16.713V183.971c0-9.229-7.525-16.715-16.716-16.715zM470.266 167.256c-2.692-.456-128.739 0-128.739 0l17.606-48.032c12.148-33.174 4.283-83.827-29.424-101.835-10.975-5.864-26.309-8.809-38.672-5.697-7.09 1.784-13.321 6.478-17.035 12.767-4.271 7.233-3.83 15.676-5.351 23.696-3.857 20.342-13.469 39.683-28.354 54.2-25.952 25.311-106.571 98.331-106.571 98.331v267.45h278.593c37.592.022 62.228-41.958 43.687-74.749 22.101-14.155 29.66-43.97 16.716-66.862 22.102-14.155 29.66-43.97 16.716-66.862 38.134-24.423 25.385-84.871-19.172-92.407z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E") center/cover no-repeat;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background:red;
}

.box:hover {
  background:blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

You can even consider gradient coloration:

```css
.box {
  -webkit-mask: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 511.999 511.999'%3E%3Cpath fill='red' d='M83.578 167.256H16.716C7.524 167.256 0 174.742 0 183.971v300.881c0 9.225 7.491 16.713 16.716 16.713h66.862c9.225 0 16.716-7.489 16.716-16.713V183.971c0-9.229-7.525-16.715-16.716-16.715zM470.266 167.256c-2.692-.456-128.739 0-128.739 0l17.606-48.032c12.148-33.174 4.283-83.827-29.424-101.835-10.975-5.864-26.309-8.809-38.672-5.697-7.09 1.784-13.321 6.478-17.035 12.767-4.271 7.233-3.83 15.676-5.351 23.696-3.857 20.342-13.469 39.683-28.354 54.2-25.952 25.311-106.571 98.331-106.571 98.331v267.45h278.593c37.592.022 62.228-41.958 43.687-74.749 22.101-14.155 29.66-43.97 16.716-66.862 22.102-14.155 29.66-43.97 16.716-66.862 38.134-24.423 25.385-84.871-19.172-92.407z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E") center/cover no-repeat;
          mask: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 511.999 511.999'%3E%3Cpath fill='red' d='M83.578 167.256H16.716C7.524 167.256 0 174.742 0 183.971v300.881c0 9.225 7.491 16.713 16.716 16.713h66.862c9.225 0 16.716-7.489 16.716-16.713V183.971c0-9.229-7.525-16.715-16.716-16.715zM470.266 167.256c-2.692-.456-128.739 0-128.739 0l17.606-48.032c12.148-33.174 4.283-83.827-29.424-101.835-10.975-5.864-26.309-8.809-38.672-5.697-7.09 1.784-13.321 6.478-17.035 12.767-4.271 7.233-3.83 15.676-5.351 23.696-3.857 20.342-13.469 39.683-28.354 54.2-25.952 25.311-106.571 98.331-106.571 98.331v267.45h278.593c37.592.022 62.228-41.958 43.687-74.749 22.101-14.155 29.66-43.97 16.716-66.862 22.102-14.155 29.66-43.97 16.716-66.862 38.134-24.423 25.385-84.871-19.172-92.407z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E") center/cover no-repeat;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background:linear-gradient(red,blue);
}

.box:hover {
  background:linear-gradient(yellow,green);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

Comment: Interesting. Never seen hue-rotate() before.  How would this work if I want to change to more specific colors?  Say it's initial filled in #33af8d and I want the hover color to be #126d7d ?  Is there some type of calculator you use to get the correct degree?

Comment: Hmm I see. Would you say the way I'm integrating these SVGs as encoded background images is the most efficient way of doing this? Would it be easier to change colors if I just link the background image to a .SVG file?

Answer (score 3):

This is my solution. I'm opting for a data uri encoding using `encodeURIComponent()`. Although encoded this will produce a readable code that you can manipulate in javascript. In this case I've written a function `setFill()` where inside the data uri I'm adding `fill='${color}'`

```js
test.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
  setFill(test, "gold");
});

test.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
  setFill(test, "black");
});

function setFill(element, color) {
  element.style.background = `url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 24 24'%3E%3Ctitle%3Ethumb up%3C/title%3E%3Cpath d='M0 0h24v24h-24z' fill='none'%3E%3C/path%3E%3Cpath fill='${color}' d='M1 21h4v-12h-4v12zm22-11c0-1.1-.9-2-2-2h-6.31l.95-4.57.03-.32c0-.41-.17-.79-.44-1.06l-1.06-1.05-6.58 6.59c-.37.36-.59.86-.59 1.41v10c0 1.1.9 2 2 2h9c.83 0 1.54-.5 1.84-1.22l3.02-7.05c.09-.23.14-.47.14-.73v-1.91l-.01-.01.01-.08z'%3E%3C/path%3E%3C/svg%3E")`;
}
```

```css
#test{
width:50px;
height:50px;
border:1px solid;
background: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 24 24'%3E%3Ctitle%3Ethumb up%3C/title%3E%3Cpath d='M0 0h24v24h-24z' fill='none'%3E%3C/path%3E%3Cpath d='M1 21h4v-12h-4v12zm22-11c0-1.1-.9-2-2-2h-6.31l.95-4.57.03-.32c0-.41-.17-.79-.44-1.06l-1.06-1.05-6.58 6.59c-.37.36-.59.86-.59 1.41v10c0 1.1.9 2 2 2h9c.83 0 1.54-.5 1.84-1.22l3.02-7.05c.09-.23.14-.47.14-.73v-1.91l-.01-.01.01-.08z'%3E%3C/path%3E%3C/svg%3E");  
}
```

```html
<div id="test" ></div>
```

This is a tool that helps you encoding SVGs using `encodeURIComponent()`: [SVG-encoder](https://codepen.io/yoksel/pen/JDqvs)

Answer (score 0):

I just tried something that worked for me.

1. Copy your code from %3Csvg to svg%3E"
2. Go to https://mothereff.in/url
3. Past your code in the URL-encoded area In the URL-decoded area above, replace the fill field with the color you want in the HEX format.
4. Find your color in the encoded format in the Url-encoded area surrounded by %27. For example, '#ff9500' <=>  %27%23ff9500%27, so #ff9500 <=> %23ff9500.
5. Copy that encoded color in your encoded code and it should work !! Let me know if it is the case