# Custom color for SVG bullet point

Tags: css, svg

I have the following CSS

```
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

ul > li::before {
  content: "";
  height: 1em;
  width: 1em;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin-left: -1.5em;
  margin-top: 7px;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  transition: background-size 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: background-size 0.3s;
}

ul > li::before {
  background-image: url(../images/check-mark.svg);
}
```

Which works fine with the HTML below

```
  <ul>
    <li>first</li>
    <li>last</li>
  </ul>
```

Now, I want to add a second list using the same check-mark but having different color.

So, I have updated my code as follows

HTML

```
   <ul class="blue">
     <li>first</li>
     <li>last</li>
   </ul>
```

CSS

```
svg {
  fill: currentColor;
}

ul.blue > li::before {
  color: blue;
}
```

But the check-mark is still black. How can I have the check-marks in the `blue` list blue?

Comment: you need to apply fiter or use another SVG (here is an idea : https://stackoverflow.com/a/54802632/8620333)

Comment: Please verify if any of the answers helped.

Answer (score 0):

You cant change the color of the image with just color: blue;
Maybe this will work:

```
ul.blue > li::before {
fill: blue;
}
```

Or just find another image with blue check mark and add it the same way like

```
ul.blue > li::before {
  background-image: url(../images/blue-check-mark.svg); 
}
```