# To fill SVG via CSS

Tags: css

My page: https://galina.xyz/makiyazh/oshibki-pri-makiyazhe/

Html:

Lorem ipsum

Css:

```
.bullet-silhouette-1:before {
    fill: red;
    background-image:  url("https://galina.xyz/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/silhouette_1.svg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    content:"";   
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;     
}
```

[image]

JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/y81nq3e9/1/

Could you help me understand why the SVG is not filled?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the bullet's color if it's a custom SVG, you can try to make red svg, then add it as a bullet :

```
.bullet-silhouette-1:before {
    /*fill: red; "delete this"*/
    background-image:  url("https://galina.xyz/.../redbullet_1.svg");
}
```

to change the color in svg:

```
<svg fill="red">
  .
  .
  .
</svg>
```

or:

```
<svg>
  .
  .
  .
  <path fill="red" />
</svg>
```

**Ref** : [custom color for SVG bullet point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55167233/custom-color-for-svg-bullet-point)

Comment: But this is editing SVG rather than using CSS.

Comment: yes, I said you cannot change it, only if it is a circle, disc, etc.. bullet