# How do I change the style of a path in an SVG?

Tags: html, css, svg

I have the following structure:

- a SVG file bar.svg that has the following structure:

  `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <svg width="100px" height="50px" version="1.1">
      <title>mySVG</title>
      <g id="mySVG" stroke="none" >
          <path d="some path" id="mySVGPath"></path>
      </g>
  </svg>`
- a HTML file where I embed the svg using `<img src="foo/bar.svg">`
- `<style></style>` inside the HTML file where I'm trying to change the color of the path by using a selector

However, due to my complete lack of experience with even the most basic HTML, I'm failing to address the path. When I do this:

```
<style>
    #mySVGPath {
        color: blue;
    }
</style>
```

Nothing happens. How would I correctly reference that particular path of my SVG in the stylesheet using a selector?

Comment: If you are using the SVG as an **image**...you can't.

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54802632/8620333