# How to apply rgba color in a black/transparent svg with img tag using CSS?

Tags: html, css, svg, rgb

I have an image

```
<img class="colorize" src="./logo.svg" alt="logo" />
```

The logo.svg is just black.

Is there a way to have a CSS class `.colorize {}` and apply a certain color, ex. red or rgba (1, 2, 3, 0.5) ?

Comment: Sure, edit the logo.svg file and put the class in it.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54800705/8620333 use the SVG as mask and you can do it

Answer (score 0):

The only way to modify an image directly from CSS is to use the filter attribute :

```css
img {
  width: 500 px;
  height: 500 px;
}

.colorize {
  filter: contrast(1000%) invert(100%) sepia(100%) saturate(10000%) hue-rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<img class="colorize" src="https://convertingcolors.com/plain-000000.svg" alt="logo" />
```

Original image :

```css
img {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<img class="colorize" src="https://convertingcolors.com/plain-000000.svg" alt="logo" />
```

More on the subject : [How to transform black into any given color using only CSS filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42966641/how-to-transform-black-into-any-given-color-using-only-css-filters)

Comment: Is there a tool where I can give an rgb() value, and find out the parameters of the filters ?

Comment: @entropyfeverone not that I know of, you'll have to do it manually.

Comment: @entropyfeverone did the question help you or should I delete it?