# Download HTML Canvas/BLOB as a PNG

Tags: javascript, canvas, download, png, sag

I’m programmatically creating multiple house images that look like this:

[image]

I'm doing this by simply iterating through a loop which:

1. Creates a new Canvas object at each iteration
2. Draws an SVG of the house onto this new Canvas object
3. Creates a PNG file from that Canvas

To get some variety going, I’m also programmatically changing the colors of each house at each iteration by simply looking up color-schemes from an Array of color-schemes I created.

All this works great.

But what I’m struggling with is getting my script to AUTOMATICALLY DOWNLOAD each newly created House ".PNG" file to my hard-drive.

I’m trying to do this by creating an ANCHOR `<a>` tag for each of my canvas/PNG’s and then calling the `“.click()”` method on each (code is below) - but it’s not working.

**Chrome** is giving me this error:

[image]

And **Firefox** gives me this error:

[image]

Any idea what needs to be done here?

My code is below.

1. Here's the basic House SVG:

   ```
        <svg id="HOUSE" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="240.26" height="311.24" viewBox="0 0 240.26 311.24">
            <defs>
                <style>
                .roof-class, .window-class, .door-class {
                    stroke: #000;
                    stroke-miterlimit: 10;
                    }
                </style>
            </defs>

            <g id="House">
                <rect class="house-class" x="30.08" y="131.74" width="173.07" height="179"/>
                <path d="M270,242V420H98V242H270m1-1H97V421H271V241Z" transform="translate(-67.39 -109.76)"/>
            </g>

            <polygon id="Roof" class="roof-class" points="1.11 131.74 239.11 131.74 117.11 0.74 1.11 131.74"/>
            <rect id="Window2" class="window-class" x="145.11" y="160.74" width="30" height="42"/>
            <rect id="Window1" class="window-class" x="58.61" y="160.74" width="30" height="42"/>
            <rect id="Door" class="door-class" x="92.11" y="228.74" width="52" height="82"/>
        </svg>
   ```
2. Then I have:

   ```
        window.onload = function() {
            alert("window.onload - yo!"); 

            let svgHolder = document.getElementById("HOUSE");
            console.log("'svgHolder' = ");
            console.log(svgHolder);
            // console.log("DIR of 'svgHolder' = " + svgHolder );

            svgHolder.onload = function() {
                console.log("==> 'svgHolder.onload' --> 'TheHouse' has been loaded!!!");
            }
        }


        // GLOBAL VARIABLES:
        const TOTAL_IMAGES = 10;
        const canvasWidth = 250;
        const canvasHeight = 320;

        var canvasX = 0;
        var canvasY = 0;

        // COLOR-SCHEME VARIABLES:
        var colorCounter = 0;

        let houseColorSchemesArray = [ 
            {
                ".house-class": "fuchsia",
                ".door-class": "darkblue",
                ".window-class": "yellow",
                ".roof-class": "maroon"
            },

            {
                ".house-class": "gold",
                ".door-class": "purple",
                ".window-class": "pink",
                ".roof-class": "crimson"
            },

            {
                ".house-class": "lightblue",
                ".door-class": "darkslategray",
                ".window-class": "lightgreen",
                ".roof-class": "darkred"
            } ,

            {
                ".house-class": "blue",
                ".door-class": "orange",
                ".window-class": "pink",
                ".roof-class": "lime"
            } 
        ];


        // CLASS-NAMES:
        let classNamesToPaintArray = [".house-class", ".door-class", ".window-class", ".roof-class"];

        // SVG Template:
        let houseSVG = document.getElementById("HOUSE");

        // var loadedImageCount = 0;

        var masterHouseImagesArray = [];


        function designOneHouse(theCanvas) {
            console.log("= =>>In 'designOneHouse()'!\n");

            let context = theCanvas.getContext("2d");

            // Now GET-AT and PAINT the Individual SVG Components.
            // STRATEGY:
            // 1. Iterate through the Array containing all the CLASS-NAMES who's color I want to change.
            // 2. For each of these classes, I'll need to iterate through all the HTML elements that are OF that class type
            //    (there may be like 10 elements that are all styled by the same Style; I want all of them to be updated!)
            // 
            let colorScheme = houseColorSchemesArray[colorCounter];
            console.log("==>>Current 'colorScheme' = ");
            console.log(colorScheme);


            console.log("\n\nNOW Going into a 'forEach' loop!");
            classNamesToPaintArray.forEach(className => {
                console.log("==>>In 'forEach', current 'className' = " + className);
                let elementsArray = houseSVG.querySelectorAll(className);

                elementsArray.forEach(element => element.style.fill = colorScheme[className]);
            });


            var imageData = houseSVG.outerHTML;
            var DOMURL = window.URL || window.webkitURL || window;
            var img = new Image();
            var svg = new Blob([imageData], { type: 'image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8' });
            var url = DOMURL.createObjectURL(svg);

            img.onload = function () {
                context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
                DOMURL.revokeObjectURL(url);

                // Now ADD this new House Image to the 'masterHouseImagesArray':
                masterHouseImagesArray.push(img);
                console.log("\n  >>>'masterHouseImagesArray' now has " + masterHouseImagesArray.length + " images in it." );


                if(masterHouseImagesArray.length == TOTAL_IMAGES) {
                    alert("ALL IMAGES ACCOUNTED FOR!!! \n>Going to make ANCHOR TAGS NOW!!!");
                    createAnchorTags();
                }

            }

            img.src = url;


            // Iterate the ColorCounter - making sure we don't overflow the ColorsArrays:
            colorCounter++;
            if(colorCounter == houseColorSchemesArray.length) {
                colorCounter = 0;
            }

            console.log("\n\nEXITING 'designOneHouse()'!\n");

        }
   ```
3. Finally, I have this:

   ```
        function makeCanvasGrid() {
            console.log("\n\n====>In 'makeCanvasGrid()'!\n");

            for(var canvasCounter = 0; canvasCounter < TOTAL_IMAGES; canvasCounter++) {
                console.log("\n >FOR LOOP - canvasCounter = " + canvasCounter);

                // 1. Create a new Canvas Object:
                let newCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
                newCanvas.setAttribute("width", canvasWidth);
                newCanvas.setAttribute("height", canvasHeight);
                newCanvas.setAttribute("id", "newCanvas" + canvasCounter);
                // Log-out just to verify the "id" property was set correctly:
                console.log("  >newCanvas.id  = " + newCanvas.id);

                // 2. Place the Canvas at (x,y) (top, left) coordinates:
                newCanvas.style.backgroundColor = "lightblue";
                newCanvas.style.position = "absolute";
                newCanvas.style.left = canvasX + "px";
                newCanvas.style.top = canvasY + "px";

                document.body.appendChild(newCanvas);

                designOneHouse(newCanvas);


                // Check the current Canvas' (X, Y) coords, and if needed, reset X to 0 and SKIP to
                // the next "ROW" of Canvasses:
                if(canvasCounter > 0 && canvasCounter % 3 == 0) {
                    console.log("  >>NEXT ROW PLEASE!!!! canvasCount = ", canvasCounter);
                    canvasX = 0;
                    canvasY += canvasHeight + 20;
                }
                else {
                    canvasX += canvasWidth + 10;
                    console.log("\n >Increasing 'canvasX' to:" + canvasX);
                }
            }

        }



        makeCanvasGrid();



        function createAnchorTags() {
            console.log("\n\n==========================\n=\n=");
            console.log("==>>In 'createAnchorTags()'!");

            for(anchorTagsCounter = 0; anchorTagsCounter < TOTAL_IMAGES; anchorTagsCounter++) {
                // 1. CREATE a new HTML "a" (anchor) TAG/Element and give it an ID:
                let newAnchorTag = document.createElement("a");
                newAnchorTag.id = "anchorTag#" + anchorTagsCounter;

                // 2. ASSIGN a value to its "href" property:
                newAnchorTag.href = masterHouseImagesArray[anchorTagsCounter].src;
                console.log("\n >newAnchorTag.href = " + newAnchorTag.href);

                // 3. ASSIGN a value to its "download" property:
                newAnchorTag.download = "PunkPass#" + anchorTagsCounter;

                // 4. APPEND this newly created ANCHOR tag/element to the page:
                document.body.appendChild(newAnchorTag);

                console.log("   ... ... ....");
                console.log("   ->'newAnchorTag' created!");
                console.log("    >'newAnchorTag.id' = " + newAnchorTag.id);


                newAnchorTag.click();
            }

        }
   ```

Would appreciate any and all help.
Thanks!

Comment: Do you have some kind of "security" extension installed on your browser?

Comment: I'm not aware of any "security" extensions (I'm also testing on at least 3 different browsers and they don't all have the same stuff installed on them) - what are some extensions I might look for that could be causing this? Like can you name some?

Comment: These NFTs look dope!

Comment: I came up with a solution and posted it to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72211735/4946681

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you should take a closer look at [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js) - a convenient library for downloading files generated on the client. There is even an example of [saving canvas in png file](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js#saving-a-canvas).

Comment: That does it. I have no idea how exactly it works, what it's doing behind the scenes - but it WORKS. Thanks!